# Getting values of a multiple allowed select

Tags: jquery, forms, select

HTML:

```
<select multiple="" name="selectinputmultiple" id="">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Console just shows the first selected value, I want to save values in an array on each change. So for example:

- If a user selected `1` and `2` => {1,2}
- Then the user unselected `1` and selected `3` => {2,3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) which should give an array

```js
$('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').on('change', function() {
  $('#log').html(JSON.stringify($(this).val()))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" name="selectinputmultiple" id="">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **map()** to get the all selected values in array

```
$('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').on('change', function () {  
    var val=$('select[name=selectinputmultiple] option:selected').map(function () {
            return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(val)
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/tnay12tf/)**

Answer (score 1):

As per **[.val() doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

> In the case of select elements, it returns null when no option is selected and an array containing the value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because the multiple attribute is present.

You can simply use:

```
var values = $('[name="selectinputmultiple"]').val();
```

Answer (score -1):

This should deinately work,

```js
 $('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').on('change', function() {
   $('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
     alert($(this).val());
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" name="selectinputmultiple" id="">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How come -1 ??? when it is giving perfect output ??

Comment: Hah, someone is giving -1 to everyone elses answers.

Comment: @nimbuz gosh WHY ? even tghough giving correct output people doing like this !

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<select multiple="" name="selectinputmultiple" id="">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

$('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').on('change', function() {
    $('select[name=selectinputmultiple]').each(function() {
       console.log($(this).val());
     });  
});
```

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxL55zuo/1/)

Comment: -1! What is the reason?